# Est-ce correct de dire "Me font vos yeux beaux mourir, belle Marquise, d’amour" ?

Tags: ordre-des-mots

> Je suis amoureux d’une personne de grande qualité, et je souhaiterais que vous m’aidassiez à lui écrire quelque chose dans un petit billet que je veux laisser tomber à ses pieds. [...]
>   Je voudrais donc lui mettre dans un billet : Belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux me font mourir d’amour ; mais je voudrais que cela fût mis d’une manière galante ; que cela fût tourné gentiment. [...]
>   Je ne veux que ces seules paroles-là dans le billet ; mais tournées à la mode, bien arrangées comme il faut. Je vous prie de me dire un peu, pour voir, les diverses manières dont on les peut mettre.

(Molière, *Le Bourgeois Gentilhomme*)

Comment: That's Cyrano de Bergerac if I am correct. Excellent shit.

Comment: This is "Le bourgeois gentilhomme", Molière.

Answer (score 3):

Non, et c'est justement là que se situe la plaisanterie. Il n'y a pas beaucoup de manières de tourner cette phrase, le seul choix est dans la position de « belle Marquise ».

> Belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux me font mourir d’amour.   *(la tournure normale)*
>   Vos beaux yeux, belle Marquise, me font mourir d’amour.
>   Vos beaux yeux me font mourir d’amour, belle Marquise.

En poésie, on pourrait éventuellement construire la phrase autrement, pour les besoins du rythme, mais cela demande du talent.

Les propositions du maître de philosophie sont absurdes. Il se moque de Monsieur Jourdain (qui ne s'en aperçoit pas), qui (en plus de ne vouloir ni prose ni vers) lui demande de varier la phrase sans changer les mots. Il y a évidemment beaucoup de manières de déclarer son amour, mais si l'on insiste pour cette phrase, il n'y a guère qu'une manière de l'écrire.

Comment: Une autre tournure idiomatique est: *Vos beaux yeux, belle Marquise, me font mourir d’amour.*

Comment: Mais du coup est-ce réellement faux ? Y a-t-il réellement des règles de syntaxe écrites noir sur blanc qui déterminent à ce point l'ordre des mots ? J'imagine qu'on dit "le chien" et pas "chien le" car c'est un article et le nom qui l'accompagne, mais y a-t-il vraiment des règles pour tous les groupes de mots ?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui, il y a des règles. Les règles ne sont pas toujours absolues, il y a des degrés, mais par exemple on ne dit jamais « chien le » ou « vos yeux beaux ».

Comment: @Gilles Mais sont-ce des règles d'usage ou de vraies règles syntaxiques et grammaticales ? « Vos yeux beaux » semble justement un exemple d'interdiction injustifiée autrement que par l'usage.

Answer (score -1):

Oui.

En latin l’ordre des mots n’a pas d’importance. On retrouve parfois dans le français cette caractéristique. Si on analyse la phrase : « Me font vos yeux beaux mourir, belle Marquise, d’amour » l’accord du verbe faire, le sujet, l’objet, le complément… il n’y a pas d’ambiguïté.

À contrario, à l’exception des adverbes, en anglais l’ordre des mots ne saurais souffrir du moindre écart…

> Vos beaux yeux me font mourir d’amour, belle Marquise

is probably the "normal" way this sentence should look…

Comment: The *maître de philosophie* would slightly disagree: **Belle marquise, vos beaux yeux me font mourir d'amour.**

Comment: Il n'y a pas d'ambiguité, parce qu'on arrive à reconstruire la phrase, mais en utilisant cet ordre de mots, monsieur Jourdain se ridiculiserait.